# Inherited truth check in condition comparison

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a clean way to get `true` or `false` based on an order of permissions based on the following rules:

1. Starts with Company Permissions as a default
2. Then to Team Permissions if permission defined
3. Finally to User Permissions if permission is

This would need to also handle `undefined`.  So basically wanting to see if there's some "clean" way to do this without having to conditionally check each value and moving on.

In this example, the result should be `false` since there are no User Permissions defined and the Team Permissions has `false`.

```js
const UserPermissions = {}

const TeamPermissions = {
  PERMISSION_ONE: false
}

const CompanyPermissions = {
  PERMISSION_ONE: true
}


const hasPermissions = UserPermissions.PERMISSION_ONE || TeamPermissions.PERMISSION_ONE || CompanyPermissions.PERMISSION_ONE 

console.log(hasPermissions)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want both `user and team permission` to be true for final result to be true ? if any of them is false it should depend on `company permission` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the same property name in multiple objects, you might be able to slightly alter the technique in georg's answer:

```js
const firstBoolProp = (...objs) => (prop) => 
  objs.reduce((a, o) => Boolean(a) === a ? a : o[prop], undefined)

const UserPermissions = {}
const TeamPermissions = {PERMISSION_ONE: false}
const CompanyPermissions = {PERMISSION_ONE: true}

console .log (
  firstBoolProp
    (UserPermissions, TeamPermissions, CompanyPermissions)
    ('PERMISSION_ONE')
)
```

You can then use a single function to multiple permissions against that same set of permission objects:

```js
const getPermissions = firstBoolProp(UserPermissions, TeamPermissions, CompanyPermissions)

const perms = {
  p1: getPermissions('PERMISSION_ONE'),
  p2: getPermissions('PERMISSION_TWO'),
}
//=> {p1: false, p2: undefined}
```

And if you want to use an array rather than individual parameters, you can simply replace `(...obj) =>` with `(obj) =>`

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, the rules are:

- ignore `undefined`
- return true of false, whatever comes first

This little function should handle that, not sure how you want to deal with empty (or all undefined) arguments.

```js
let x;
let t = true;
let f = false;

let firstBool = (...a) => Boolean(a.filter(x => typeof x !== 'undefined').shift());

console.log(firstBool(x,t,f));
console.log(firstBool(t,x,f));
console.log(firstBool(x,f,t));
console.log(firstBool());
```

In your example, that would be

```
 const hasPermissions = firstBool(
     UserPermissions.PERMISSION_ONE,
     TeamPermissions.PERMISSION_ONE,
     CompanyPermissions.PERMISSION_ONE 
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store the permissions in an array and reduce it to a boolean:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {{PERMISSION_ONE:boolean}[]} permissions
 */
function anyoneHasPermission(permissions, name = "PERMISSION_ONE") {
    for (const perm of permissions) {
        if (perm[name]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
console.log(anyoneHasPermission([UserPermissions, TeamPermissions, CompanyPermissions]))
```

You need to be more specific in what you want to accomplish. Choosing the right data structure is usually more important than choosing an algorithm. Indeed, sometimes the right data structure makes the algorithm disappear completely.

Comment: No, it should return false if it comes first.

Comment: If you're going to "reduce" an array, why wouldn't you use `Array.prototype.reduce`?

Answer (score 0):

Throw the permissions into an array in the order that you want them validated.

Iterate the array and if any of your conditions is not met then return false and break.

This will stop you running down the entire chain if say your top level permission is not set (because nothing beyond that matters anymore and no use validating it)

```js
const UserPermissions = {PERMISSION_ONE: true}
const TeamPermissions = {}
const CompanyPermissions = {PERMISSION_ONE: true}

const permCheck = HasPerms([CompanyPermissions, TeamPermissions, UserPermissions]);
alert(permCheck);

function HasPerms(permArray){
  for (var i = 0; i < permArray.length; i++) {
    if (!permArray[i] || !permArray[i].PERMISSION_ONE) {return false;}
  }
  return true;
}
```

You can expand the function to dynamically take in the permission you would like to check but example shown hardcoded for simplicity sake.